JWT rotation for SSR or CSR
We built a web application which has one backend server, and one frontend server with CSR(something similar SPA + SSR).
And users do login then get short life-cycled access token and long refresh token.
For security improvement, refresh token is httponly cookie and has db based blacklist for logout tokens.
So if access token is expired, server throws 401 error with new refresh token and client server retries with it.
All works well, but when multiple API calls executed asynchronously, then only first call can be retried, others using expired blacklisted tokens so fails.
I fix it by add short period for invalid blacklisted token, but it works not sometimes or in webviews likes flutter.
Is there any best solution for this?
I found some articles in stackoverflow, but in CSR, frontend server cannot update httponly refresh token cookie in server side.
